# How to address a segment declared in another module?

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

Until now, if I wanted to address some var declared in another segment and/or declared in the same segment but in a different module, I'd just use the public/extrn pair to get away with it.

```
; declaring module .asm
public some_var
otherseg segment para public 'code'
    some_var db ?
otherseg ends

; referencing module .asm
extern some_var:byte
otherseg segment para public 'code'
    test_proc proc
        mov ax, [some_var]
    test_proc endp
otherseg ends
```

But now I need to access the int vector table and also some other parts of a BIOS/DOS program memory, so I declared an 'AT' segment like this:

```
memmap segment public at 0000h
    ; some int vector addresses I'll be using.
    org 13h * 4
    orig_int_13h dw ?

    ; BIOS addr

    ; other interesting memory addrs

    ; graphic memory
    org 0B800h
    text_mode_base_addr dw ?

memmap ends
```

The problem is that it's declared in another file and I don't know how to make it visible to the module I'm referencing it from.

```
; read some vector addr
mov ax, offset memmap  ; error memmap no declared
mov es, ax
mov bx, es:[text_mode_base_addr]  ; reads top left character in the screen
```

If I declare the AT segment in the same file it will work.

How can I use a segment declared in another file?
Please note that I'd like to do this without using 'include' magic.

Comment: Segment declarations cannot be exported, they must be redeclared in each file. The `AT` directive is *combination attribute* so segment declarations are supposed to work this way I'm afraid.

Comment: @MargaretBloom So then it makes sense to put segment declarations in include files I guess?

Comment: I wonder if this is something that simply MASM doesn't do or there's a good reason for not letting segment addresses to be exported like any other symbol,

Comment: TASM do it too, but it followed MASM. The TASM manual ([here](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf), page 183) states that only labels, EQU and vars can be made public. You can use a common include or redeclare in each module only the segments needed (as a form of documentation).

Comment: Can't you extract the segment by using some label (public symbol) inside it, like `mov ax, SEG orig_int_13h`? BTW `org 0B800h` is wrong, that's `0000:B800` address, not `B800:0000`, which can't be even reached through `0000` segment at all. ... anyway, most of the people didn't bother to define whole segment with `AT` for `0000` and `B800`, they simply used something as `BIOS_SEGMENT EQU 0` and then `mov ax,BIOS_SEGMENT` `mov ds,ax` ... also defining the specific interesting addresses as `EQU` constants. The mapped segment full of `org` directives looks to me quite cumbersome & overly complex.

Comment: @Ped7g You're right about trying to address 0B800h like that, I just wrote it all from the top of my head. I've been doing some research and it seems that MASM treats AT segments quite differently, maybe they should've chosen a different name to shape this concept. If I remember other compilers like FASM have the 'virtual' directive to do that.